# libinput palm detection not working

Tags: debian, touchpad, libinput

I recently bought a new Dell XPS 15 and installed Debian on it. It previously ran Windows 10, and the palm detection/rejection worked perfectly, just as I would have expected. But now, running Debian and using `libinput`, palm detection is (as far as I can tell) non-existant/completely broken.

Output of `xinput | grep -i touchpad`:

```
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Output of `xinput list-props 13`:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (116):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (118): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (269): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (270): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (271):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (272):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (273):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (274):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (275):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (276):  1, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (251): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (252): 0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (256):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (257):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (236): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (237):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (238):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (258): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (259): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (260):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (261):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (262):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (277): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (278):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (279):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (265):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (266):    0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (280):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (281):    1
    Device Node (239):  "/dev/input/event1"
    Device Product ID (240):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (267):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (268):   1
```

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver          "libinput"
        Option          "Tapping"                       "on"
        Option          "TappingDrag"                   "on"
EndSection
```

A [sample of input events](https://pastebin.com/GdXwm7tc) generated with `sudo evemu-record /dev/input/event1 >> eventlog-finger.log`, using my finger on the touchpad as I do during normal usage.

A [sample of input events](https://pastebin.com/947G3A6a) generated with `sudo evemu-record /dev/input/event1 >> eventlog-palm.log`, using my palm on the touchpad as happens while I try to type.

If you look at the event logs, you'll see that `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` only appears once at the beginning of each log. From what I've found, [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182093) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1245328), this is a (somewhat) known issue where `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` is never reported as anything other than 0. This apparently breaks palm detection using synaptics drivers, and I'm assuming in libinput as well.

Trying to do anything on my laptop without plugging in an external mouse and disabling the touchpad is almost impossible, the mouse jumps and more troubling, sometimes my palm can click the touchpad, making me type somewhere unpredictable or nowhere at all.

If anyone knows anything at all as to how to even *start* fixing this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I should mention that I *have* already tried using Synaptics touchpad drivers, including doing the following:

```
apt install -y xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

and then by messing with the following settings to no avail:

```
synclient PalmMinWidth=4
synclient PalmMinZ=80
```

I've tried everything between 0 and 15 for `PalmMinWidth` and 50 through 150 for `PalmMinZ`. *Nothing* works. But if it wasn't already clear - I already know that this is because `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` **is not reported**. That much I'm sure of, and therefore that is not the basis of my question - my question pertains to how I would go about fixing the reporting of `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` or another workaround that would yield a similar result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many weeks of major annoyances and I finally came to the stupidly simple solution of:

*just upgrade the packages*.

I downloaded the following 4 packages:

- `libinput10_1.11.3-1_amd64.deb`
- `libinput-bin_1.11.3-1_amd64.deb`
- `libwacom2_0.30-1_amd64.deb`
- `libwacom-common_0.30-1_all.deb`

And installed them with `dpkg` as follows:

```
trevor@xps:~$ cd ~/downloads/
trevor@xps:~$ sudo dpkg -i libwacom-common_0.30-1_all.deb
...dpkg runs...
trevor@xps:~$ sudo dpkg -i libwacom2_0.30-1_amd64.deb
...dpkg runs...
trevor@xps:~$ sudo dpkg -i libinput-bin_1.11.3-1_amd64.deb
...dpkg runs...
trevor@xps:~$ sudo dpkg -i libinput10_1.11.3-1_amd64.deb
...dpkg runs...
```

And restarted my system (restarting X should work as well).
After my laptop booted back up, palm detection worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` with the content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver          "synaptics"
        Option          "PalmDetect"          "1"
        Option          "PalmMinWidth"        "5"
        Option          "PalmMinZ"            "100"
EndSection
```

Reboot your laptop afterwards to apply new configuration. Play with `PalmMinWidth` option to achieve best result - try values `3`, `4` etc.

Another way is to set properties temporarily, just execute in terminal:

```
xinput set-prop 13 "Synaptics Palm Detection" 1
xinput set-prop 13 "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" 5, 5
```

Try different values for `Synaptics Palm Dimensions`.

Read additionally [synaptics - Synaptics touchpad input driver](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html).

Comment: Nope - I've already tried Synaptics drivers any it makes no difference. As I noted in my post, Synaptics Palm detection*completely* breaks when `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` isn't reported. I've tested the above settings while using Synaptics drivers and they do not work to fix palm detection.

Comment: I should also note that with Synaptics drivers you don't need to reboot the machine, if you directly edit the config file you can just restart your desktop manager (for me, `lightdm`, so I would use `systemctl restart lightdm`, but substitute in your desktop manager), or even just use `synclient` if you're making temporary/test changes to the touchpad driver properties. But either way, if possible you should be using `libinput` as it is an overall better and more well maintained driver package.

Comment: @TrevorSears I know, but one person uses lightdm, another person - gdm etc., this is the reason why I have suggested to reboot - the way is universal.

Comment: if you want a canonicalized version, you could just kill X.

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer is not really for the specific scenario (OS, laptop model etc.), but I had to mention what fixed it for me.

I'm using Fedora 38 with KDE Plasma 5.27 and X11 on Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 4.

For some reason I've installed:

```
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-devel 1.9.2-3.fc38
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-legacy 1.9.2-3.fc38
```

These rpms were the root cause of everything. After removing them and left only with `libinput`, palm detection (despite that there's no such setting/config in the KDE Settings anymore after removing the above packages) started working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

libinput does pressure-based palm detection but it needs the thresholds, see his link here: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html

That's all you can do here because the tool width is never set (though libinput doesn't look at that anyway), but chances are high that once you set the pressure in a quirk file  (or hwdb if you're on libinput <= 1.11) it'll work.

File a bug please once you have identified the pressure threshold.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I have a really old version of libinput, I have no libinput command.

Comment: right, your version is around a year old then, which means there's a high chance it's been fixed upstream. already anway.

Comment: Your answer guided me to my eventual solution - I just ended up (somewhat dangerously) directly upgrading the necessary libinput packages and their dependencies as noted in my answer.